# How to write case insensitive Javascript search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, html-table

Example:

I have string "Waheed"  so when try to search with small letters as "waheed" the results are not coming but when I search case it is working fine.. so how can I make it not case sensitive..?
The table data is coming from php loop so iIcan not change it to lower or uppercase..!
And this is my Javascript code:

```
$("#searchStudent").on("keyup", function() {        
    var value = $(this).val();      
    if(value!='') {         
        $("table tbody tr").hide();         
        }else{          
        $("table tbody tr").show();         
    }       
    $('table tbody tr td:contains("'+value+'")').parent('tr').show();       
});
```

Comment: Don't see this as a duplicate... OP is not looking for a jQuery answer - not tagged.

Comment: Could you make split the string and make the first letter caps

Comment: @rasmeister "jQuery not tagged", but jQuery is used.

Comment: Some people may write their name first letter as small so i can not do that @LiverpoolCoder

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I think you may need to use a RegExp and use the `i` flag.

Comment: @rasmeister OP is trying to use jQuery Contains and the suggested duplicate shows how to make it work. Seems fine to me.

Comment: You can use `toLowerCase()`

Comment: Post your PHP loop

Comment: the value variable will be filled from textbox right? and where are you comparing it in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#searchStudent").on("keyup", function() {        
var value = $(this).val();      
if(value!='') {         
    $("table tbody tr").hide();         
    }else{          
    $("table tbody tr").show();         
}       
$('table tbody tr td:contains("'+ value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1) +'")').parent('tr').show();       
});
```

maybe try something like this

Comment: There is a chance of getting the first letter as small as well @Liverpool

Comment: This will make the first letter always capitalised